# getting started linking css and html

Tags: java, html, css

I am currently learning programing by myself, just learned a little bit about html and css. I been using codecademy.com witch I find very good, but I'm kinda lost on how to start. For instance, I learned how to create html page but I got lost on how to add the css or the java. I downloaded sublimetext but I can't find a tutorial specifically on linking css and java to html, or just the css would be enough for now. I saw something about linking document, but I don't know if it's the name of document or address where can be  found, please advice.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

considering this is your case (please be exact in your questions and consider adding some code)

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylefile.css">
  <script src="javascriptfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  This is your document content
</body>
</html>
```

---

BTW while asking questions in StackExchange network, please consider [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) section notes.

Comment: but the three need to be in the same software like sublime text? that's what i don't understand.

Comment: Please clear out your question body and 1- what is your exact condition 2- say what is your exact desirable output. I think I dotn even know what are you talking about. try to be concise and clear